# Removing multiple annotations from MapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

In my app I have two functionality when my tableview loads ,in the mapview all the pins are shown corresponding to tableData.NOw I have search bar which gives another set of values which I have to show on my mapView.Everything is working fine but second time previous pins are also shown means prevoius annotations are not deleted .
So please tell me how to remove prevoius annotation so that I can show only relavent pins on mapView
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the MKMapView instance method "removeAnnotations:":

```
-(void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

If you want to remove all of them you can do somethign like :

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

P.S: Beware that you might want to iterate through the annotations not to remove the userLocation (blue dot)

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: actually you I did not know what to pass in this method,It was not clear what did mapView.annotatins means but anyways thanks for ur answer.

Comment: Now i came to know i have pass an array that contains all the annotations.

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer my self:-

mapAddAnnotations is my arrayname and map is my mkmapview object.

```
[map removeAnnotations:self.mapAddAnnotations];
```